# Best way to build a 500 item menu

Tags: menus

I have a site that needs to have about 500 menu items. It's a sports site that has the following types of items

League (NFL, NBA, etc) [ About 8 top level items]
  Division (NFC East, NFC West, etc) [ about 8 second tier items per top level]
    Team (Seattle Seahawks, Denver Broncos, etc) [ about 4 third tier items per 2nd tier]

We have every major sport and all associated divisions and teams.

We are hosting on WPEngine and having difficulty saving the menu due to requests limits and that the menu saves through GET params.

Any suggestions on the best/cleanest way to build a menu?

Comment: Are all entries a complete set of these items, or do you actually need some manual tweaks?

Comment: I'm not following the question?

Comment: Do you always need all terms/posts from a specific type? In that case, you can populate the menu with your own queries instead of the menu management in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I get it that the menu is generated via queries, hence the bottlenecks. If things don't change too often, it's much more efficient to build it manually (or simply just copy the generated html and paste it back instead of source). If things do change often, cache it.

Comment: Sure but the problem is that I can't even build the menu at all because the hosting doesn't allow this many queries in one post from the admin menu panel

Comment: a) talk them into temporarily raising the limit, b) build it on a local install, c) do it manually in the first place. Either way it's less work than rewriting the whole thing just to risk finding out that it's still not nimble enough.